# General formula for solving $a^N < \epsilon$ for $0<a<1$ and $N,\epsilon > 0$

Tags: analysis

As stated in the title, I am given $a^N < \epsilon$ for $0<a<1$ and $N,\epsilon > 0$ and need to state the "general formula" for solving this. I'm not exactly sure what they mean by "general formula".

The best that I can think of is to use Newton's method on this problem until the output returned on some $j^{th}$ iteration is less than the desired $\epsilon$.

Also, the problem never states whether $N$ is part of the real numbers of the natural numbers.

Either way, I think my idea would work to get a solution, but I'm still thrown off by this phrasing of "general formula" like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using logarithms:

$$
a^N<\epsilon \quad \iff \quad N\ln a<\ln \epsilon
$$

since $0<a<1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \ln a <0$:

$$
N>\frac{\ln \epsilon}{\ln a}
$$

Comment: Makes total sense. I'm just not sure if this is the kind of answer they want. It's an applied analysis course, so it almost feels like this type of solution is "too simple." Maybe I'm just paranoid.

Comment: You can justify the first step noting that $\ln x$ is a monotone increasing function and if you want $N$ integer you can use the floor or ceiling function. But the key of the answer is simple... and not all the problems in analysis are complex.